# Código limpio y preferencias

Tags: c

espero que se encuentren de la mejor forma.

Vengo con dos preguntas referentes al título, empezaremos con la pregunta sobre el código limpio y es el sector de código `int i,j,k=0,k1=0,l,l1=0,r1=0,q1=0,r=0,q=0;` se ve de forma horrorosa, quisiera hacer que todas estas variables las pudiera definir en cero sin tener que estar una por una.

La segunda es sobre los Ifs; quiero que en especial el primer if cuente la cantidad de K++ y después empiece con el otro if sin tener que hacer el ciclo completo o hacer dos For, ejemplo:

```
[1]Azul 
[2]Azul
[3]Azul
[1]Rojo
[2]Rojo
[3]Rojo
[1]Verde
[2]Verde
```

Y no

```
[1]Azul
[1]Rojo
[2]Verde ....
```

Gracias.

```
int cont_actividad (cadenaCaracteres actividad[DIA][HORA],cadenaCaracteres vec_actividad[4])
{
    int i,j,k=0,k1=0,l,l1=0,r1=0,q1=0,r=0,q=0;
    
    for (i = 0; i < DIA; ++i)
    {   
        for (j = 0; j < HORA; ++j)
        {
            if(actividad[i][j]==vec_actividad[0])
            {
                    k++;
                    k1++;
            }
            
            if(actividad[i][j]==vec_actividad[1])
            {
                    l++;
                    l1++;
            }
            if(actividad[i][j]==vec_actividad[2])
            {
                    r++;
                    r1++;
            }
            
            if(actividad[i][j]==vec_actividad[3])
            {
                    q++;
                    q1++;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes las variables `k` y `k1`. Ambas parten de cero y se incrementan juntas. Es decir, `k1` es redundante, pues siempre valdrá lo mismo que `k`. Lo mismo para las restantes `l`, `r` y `q`.

Ahora puedo reemplazar esas cuatro variables por un solo arreglo de contadores, representado por cuatro enteros e inicializarlos todos en 0 en una sola línea:

```
int contadores[] = {0, 0, 0, 0};
```

Entonces, `k` es `contadores[0]`, `l` es `contadores[1]`, etc.

También puedo eliminar las definiciones de las variables de control de los ciclos `for`, definiendolas *in-place*:

```
for (int i = 0; i < DIA; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < HORA; j++) {
```

Y tambien puedo eliminar los `if`, ya que todos siguen el mismo patrón, y colocarlo dentro de un `for` que recorra las posibilidades de `vec_actividad`

```
for (int k = 0; k < 4; k++) {
    if (actividad[i][j] == vec_actividad[k]) {
        contadores[k]++;
    }
```

El código completo se reduce a:

```
int cont_actividad(char actividad[DIA][HORA], char vec_actividad[4]) {
    int contadores[] = {0, 0, 0, 0};
    for (int i = 0; i < DIA; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < HORA; j++) {
            for (int k = 0; k < 4; k++) {
                if (actividad[i][j] == vec_actividad[k]) {
                    contadores[k]++;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Sólo queda reemplazar el valor `4` con alguna variable simbólica con nombre adecuado.